# How can I forbid AVPlayer switching to audio only tracks in HLS stream

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, avplayer, http-live-streaming

The main source of my worries comes from the m3u8 manifests I use to play video in my app.
They contain variants with audio & video and some containing only audio.

The problem occurs when I load this type of manifest in avplayercontroller/avplayer while having a bad network or low bandwidth.
In every case avplayer witch to the tracks with no video to clear some bandwidth, resulting in no image appearing on the player.
I would like to know if there is a way to force avplayer or avplayercontroller to only focus on the manifest tracks containing audio and video and forbid audio only tracks to be selected, loaded, and played.

Thank you in advance to any tips or pointers you can give me on this subject.

Comment: I don't believe AVPlayer has any options to set a minimum bitrate (would be nice).  Could you remove the lower bandwidth variants inside the manifest?

Comment: @Martin - I'm also facing ...similar issue